# What is the error The data types varchar and datetime2 are incompatible in the add operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

```
DECLARE @State VARCHAR(32) =NULL,
        @Industry varchar(128)= NULL,
        @ListSource varchar(128) = NULL,
        @TimeZone VARCHAR(30) =NULL
DECLARE @Today DATETIME
SET     @Today = GETDATE() 
DECLARE @sSQL NVARCHAR(3000)
SET @State=1
SET @Industry=1
SET @ListSource=1
SET @TimeZone=5
SET @sSQL = 
'SELECT top 20 p.ID'+ 
CHAR(10) +'from dbo.Prospects P WITH (NOLOCK)'+ CHAR(10) +
'where p.State=ISNULL('+ CHAR(39)+@State +CHAR(39)+','+'p.State)'+ CHAR(10) +
'AND p.Industry ='+@Industry + CHAR(10) +'AND p.ListSource='+@ListSource+ CHAR(10) +'
AND p.StatusID not in(-1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,12,13,14)'+ CHAR(10) +'
AND isnull(p.PushDate,'+CHAR(39)+'1/1/1900'+CHAR(39)+')<='+CHAR(39)+@Today+CHAR(39)+
CHAR(10) +'AND p.TimeZone ='+@TimeZone+ CHAR(10) +'
order by isnull(p.LastActivityDate,'+CHAR(39)+'1/1/1900'+CHAR(39)+')'
```

Comment: Please pay more attention to the formatting of your post. It's *really* hard to read with all those blank lines. Next, include some *text* in your question. You haven't said what you're trying to achieve. Next, that's way more SQL than you need to demonstrate your problem - cut it down to as short an example as you can.

Comment: Sorry about the formatting, I am getting the error the incompatible satatypes.The data type I am passing for the variable @Today is Datetime and I guess it picks it up as string.Should I cast it to make it work

Comment: See my answer. But you can still vastly improve the question, by reducing it to just a few lines. You should also tell us what you're trying to achieve - as I state in my answer, your current approach is a really bad idea.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the immediate problem:

```
')<='+CHAR(39)+@Today+CHAR(39)
```

You're trying to use a `DATETIME` in string concatenation. A date isn't text - it's a date. So if you want to use it in string concatenation, you need to convert it to text first, e.g.

```
')<=' + CHAR(39) + CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), @Today, 126) + CHAR(39)
```

(See [CAST and CONVERT documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187928.aspx) for the available styles. Style 126 takes 23 characters, by my reckoning.)

The *next* problem is that building up SQL like this is horribly insecure - you're vulnerable to SQL injection attacks even if the client did the right thing and called you using parameters. You haven't shown us what you're *doing* with `sSQL`, but you should try as hard as you can not to building up dynamic SQL. There's almost *certainly* a better solution available. By avoiding dynamic SQL, you'll end up with:

- *Much* more readable code (every `CHAR(39)` would go, along with the string concatenation)
- Security against SQL injection attacks
- Fewer conversions between non-text values and text, which reduces the opportunity for error

Comment: Thanks for the Inputs, I want to insert the select statement into a temp table , and reference the results in another select query. The original select was performing poorly because of the ISNULL in the where clause

Comment: @user3442679: You wanted to store the statement itself in a table? That sounds like a bad idea. Why not just store the data itself?

Answer (score 1):

When concatenating `@Today`, you must convert it to `VARCHAR` first to prevent error.

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @Today, 101)
```